# Visual Studio (2005 & 2008) Compile Completed Alert?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

Does anyone know of any kind of plugin or alert system which will let me know when my compiles are completed? Some of the solutions I work with are gigantic and sometimes the compiles can take 5-20 minutes (depending on the PC). Thus I would like to do something else in the meantime, but I don't want to keep checking back to see if the compile is done. Is there any way to have a windows alert, or flash the screen when the compile is done?

It would let me browse the internet whilst waiting for the compile to finish without worrying that its been complete and I'm just wasting time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnBuildDone

```
Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildDone( _
ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, _
ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) _
Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone
'Alert that we finished building!
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Build is complete!")
End Sub
```

http://visualstudiohacks.com/general/customize-your-project-build-process/

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using PostBuild events? The reason I ask is because its in a version controlled solution, and most likely not everyone else is going to want this.

Answer (score 16):

Another way is a sound cue.  Control Panel + Sound, Sound tab.  In the Program Events list, locate the "Microsoft Visual Studio Macros" group, assign sounds to "Build Failed" and "Build Succeeded".

Comment: I needed some quick soln like this. It will save my lot of time. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Growl 
http://www.growlforwindows.com
 + visual studio plugin 
 http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/plugins/visualstudio

All the power of a notification system, including history, network broadcast, etc.

The same exits for snarl, another notification system on pc, same capabilities I guess

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Post Build Event Commands.

[Here's a tutorial](http://visualstudiohacks.com/general/customize-your-project-build-process/)